# Most efficient way to design database for tagging system

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, tags

Im new to database design and I would like to know what is the best way to design a tagging system such as the one that stackoverflow has?

I found multiple ways to design such a system on the web, but not sure which one is the most optimal.

Comment: Optimal for what? Space, time? Would you like to favour reads or writes? Unless you narrow the focus of your question, no good answer can be given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about three tables - one of the entities that is to be tagged, one table that is the tags, and then a final table to link it all together?

EDIT: Another way to do it is to use two tables, one for the entities and one for the tags.  Of course, you could use a No-SQL solution that directly supports tags.

Comment: In the three table system you would just relate the tagged entity to a different tag.

Comment: Yes, using the three table system requires a lookup on insert (but no extra overhead needed for read operations).